# R: How to read in Large Dataset (>35 MM rows) with R on Windows piece by piece?

Tags: r, large-data

How do you read in / manipulate datasets in R which exceed the allotted memory limit?

**EDIT: 
Great help so far, thanks. Let me add an additional constraint. The server is enterprise owned and I do not have administrative access. Is there a way to read partial files using read.table or something similar (e.g., by designating nrows to only read 100,000 rows at a time)? Need a workaround which can run with current environment so cannot use fread, bigmemory, etc.**

My target dataset contains approx 32 million rows with 30 columns, divided into 12 approximately equal files (some readable, some not).

The files are "|" delimited and stored on a remote serve in 12 individual files. About half of the files can be read using R, the other half exceed the allowable limit.

I'm using a simple read and rbind script:

```
path<-"filepath/mydata/contains 12 files.txt/"
fulldf<-data.frame()
for(i in 1:length(dir(path))){
    file1<-read.table(file=paste0(path,dir(path[i]), sep="|", fill=T, quote="\"")
    fulldf<-rbind(fulldf,file2)
}
```

I'd primarily like to be able to subset the data and write it to a .csv (e.g., read the data piece by piece, subset by location then rbind), but some of the files are simply too big to even read in.

Is there a way to read in part of a large file piece by piece, i.e., split an unreadable file into readable pieces?

System:
Microsoft Windows Server 2003 R2
Enterprise Edition
Service Pack 2

Computer:
Intel(R)Xeon(TM) MP CPU
3.66GHz
3.67 GHz, 12.0 GB RAM
Physical Address Extension

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 2.12.1 (2010-12-16)
Platform: i386-pc-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] data.table_1.7.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_2.12.1
```

Comment: Even the most basic googling would lead you to several options, including **ff**, **bigmemory** or the probably preferable usage of any relational database from R. (A side note: your R is _badly_ out of date. Upgrading may save you many unnecessary headaches.)

Comment: Upgrade your R to 3.0.2, install [sqlite](http://www.sqlite.org) to your machine and use [dplyr](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr).

Answer (score 0):

I think [iotools](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/iotools/index.html) with the `chunk.reader`, `read.chunk` and `chunk.apply` may be what you are looking for.

If you cannot install packages then I gather `read.table` with the `nrows` and `skip` arguments should do? You can use the `colClasses` argument to ensure that they all have the same column class.